# What are the anomalies/fault/outliers detection algorithms

Tags: time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection, one-class

I'm working on a weather application that uses data coming from multiple sensors in real time (the data is time series), i've made an anomalies detection model using One Class Support Vector Machines, and it's working good.
I need to do a benchmarking on that results.
What are the anomalies/fault/outliers detection algorithms that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

Intervention Detection facilitates outlier detection https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/09c4/ba8dd3cc88289caf18d71e8985bdd11ad21c.pdf AND here http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/uts/lec10-08.pdf .

These procedures are easily implemented in a SARMAX model as the I's https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf where causal series (the X's) can be included.